# How to call a custom layout update handle in catalog.xml?

Tags: blocks, layout-update, custom-block

I need a custom page that uses a lot of methods from an existing block class.
For the beginning I created a new layout update handle in the catalog.xml:

```
<catalog_category_secretpage>
// some references
// some blocks
</catalog_category_secretpage>
```

At this point I stuck because I don't know how to call that page/url in the browser.

```
https://myshop/catalog/category/secretpage/
```

didn't work.

Also I'm not sure if it is better to create an own module instead of extending an existing one because the new custom page doesn't really belong to that module.
But when I go that way and create a new module the I have no clue how to use my block class from the other module.

Answer (score 4):

That's a lot of questions and hard to give a comprehensive answer without context. But I'll give you some hints.

First, you always need a controller if you add new routes (i.e. URLs). There are two options for this:

1. Add a controller to an existing front name. You would add a `CategoryController` with a `secretpageAction` in your custom module and configure it for the front name `category`. This will handle your `catalog/category/secretpage` route.
2. Add a new front name for your module. The URL would then be `newfrontname/newcontrollername/newactionname`

Second, you can use block classes from any module

```
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="newblock" />
```

or extend them if you need to implement additional methods

```
class Your_Module_Block_Product extends Mage_Catalog_Product_List
```

You can also reuse complete layout handles like this:

```
<newfrontname_newcontrollername_newactionname>
    <update handle="catalog_category_view" />
</newfrontname_newcontrollername_newactionname>
```

Comment: Alright that's it I was concerned about. We have no controller in our module just using the core catalogcontroller so I didn't understand how to call that layout update handle without a controller action.

Answer (score 1):

You will also need a controller if you want to create your page.

I would recommend you to read some articles on the subject. AlanStorm made some very good ones, [this one will answer your questions](http://alanstorm.com/magento_controller_hello_world).

And yes, creating a new module is the way to go. You don't want to modify the core files, because your modifications could be erased with an upgrade of Magento, or a security patch.

To use your own blocks, you just have to specify the block in the layout, like you do in any handle. It would be something like that :

```
<block type="namespace_module/block" name="name" template="template.phtml"/>
```

If you are not really sure about that neither, you can read [this other article](http://alanstorm.com/layouts_blocks_and_templates) also from AlanStorm.